# Rails - client_side_validations doesn't work on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, assets

I'm using [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem, this is what I have in Gemfile:

```
#gem "client_side_validations", "~> 3.2.6"
gem 'client_side_validations', git: 'https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git', branch: '3-1-stable' # working well on localhost as the line above
```

For deployment to Amazon EC2 is used Capistrano gem, but when I deploy the code and check the website, I see following error in logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'rails.validations'
  (in /home/deployer/xxx/releases/20130922134530/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)):
    3:     %title xxx
    4:     %meta{:name => "msvalidate.01", :content => "70FDF21E6271BE469BC86873DE55F921"}
    5:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    6:     = javascript_include_tag "application"
    7:     = filepicker_js_include_tag
    8:     %link{:href => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic', :rel => 'stylesheet', :type => 'text/css'}
    9:     :javascript
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___4198895688777468705_70291650639660'
```

It looks like there are some troubles with installation of this gem on EC2. I am using this gem in several projects on Heroku and everything is working well, but I cannot make it work on Amazon EC2.

Is there anything what am I missing or?

Thank you

Comment: Did you precompile the assets?

Comment: On localhost or production? Not sure how it should be correctly done.

Comment: Run rake assets:precompile on the server